# Is there a way to apply a conditional against a list of values in a jsonb object?

Tags: sql, postgresql, kotlin

Currently, I have a jsonb column in a PostgreSQL table which stores a json object with the format

```
{
  "subscriptions": {
    "subscription1": {
      "subscribed": boolean
    },
    "subscription2": {
      "subscribed": boolean
    }
  }
}
```

There can be any number of subscription1/2/etc. in the document, all with different names. I'm trying to find out if the document contains **subscriptions.subscription1.subscribed == true**, etc. for each subscription type I have.

I have a list of the subscription keys I need to query, so my first instinct was to iterate over them and query the DB to get these counts:

```
subscriptionsKeys.forEach { subscription ->
    // find number of users where `subscription` == true
    val queryResult = repository.getNumberOfUsersSubscribed(subscription)

    // queryResult contains the number of users subscribed to `subscription`
}
```

Where getNumberOfUsersSubscribed() is defined as:

```
@SqlQuery(
    """
    SELECT count(*) as number_of_users FROM table
    WHERE jsonb_extract_path_text(body,'subscriptions',:subscriptionKey,'subscribed') = 'true'
    """
)
fun getNumberOfUsersSubscribedToOptOutList(
    subscriptionKey: String
): Int
```

This works fine, but for a large number of subscriptions, it means I will be doing a count(*) on the table *n* number of times, which in our production environment is over 60 queries each operating on 45 million+ records.

I'm hoping there is some way to construct a SQL/jsonb query that allows me to pass in a list/array of keys ['subscription1','subscription2',etc] that will apply the above  `= true` conditional against the input list for each row, and then return the results in the following example format:

```
+------------------------------------+
| subscription_key | number_of_users |
+------------------+-----------------+
| subscription1    | 6               |
| subscription2    | 59              |
| etc.             | n               |
+------------------+-----------------+
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as your library allows you to pass an array into a `text[]` placeholder, then this should work.  It will not be particularly fast, though, but it should be faster than the method you already have working.

```
with yourtable (id, body) as (
  values (1, '{
  "subscriptions": {
    "subscription1": {
      "subscribed": true
    },
    "subscription2": {
      "subscribed": true
    }
  }
}'::jsonb)
), search_terms as (
  select * 
    from unnest(array['subscription1', 'subscription2']) as st(term)
)
select st.term, count(*) 
  from yourtable y
       cross join lateral jsonb_each(y.body->'subscriptions') as b(k, v)
       join search_terms st 
         on st.term = b.k
        and b.v->>'subscribed' = 'true'
 group by st.term
;

┌───────────────┬───────┐
│     term      │ count │
├───────────────┼───────┤
│ subscription1 │     1 │
│ subscription2 │     1 │
└───────────────┴───────┘
(2 rows)
```

Per your comment, in case you want to count subscriptions that are not explicitly showing `subscribed` as `false`:

```
with yourtable (id, body) as (
  values (1, '{
  "subscriptions": {
    "subscription1": {
      "subscribed": true
    },
    "subscription2": {
      "subscribed": true
    },
    "subscription3": {
      "subscribed": false
    }
  }
}'::jsonb),
        (2, '{
  "subscriptions": {
    "subscription1": {
      "subscribed": true
    },
    "subscription2": {
      "subscribed": true
    },
    "subscription3": {
      "subscribed": false
    }
  }
}'::jsonb),
        (3, '{}'::jsonb)
), search_terms as (
  select * 
    from unnest(array['subscription1', 'subscription2', 'subscription3', 'subscription4']) as st(term)
)
select st.term, 
       count(*) 
         filter (where 
           coalesce(
             body->'subscriptions'
               ->st.term 
               ->>'subscribed', ''
           ) != 'false')
  from yourtable t
       cross join search_terms st
 group by st.term
 order by st.term
;

┌───────────────┬───────┐
│     term      │ count │
├───────────────┼───────┤
│ subscription1 │     3 │
│ subscription2 │     3 │
│ subscription3 │     1 │
│ subscription4 │     3 │
└───────────────┴───────┘
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Awesome! This seems to work great. I am curious if you would also know how to modify it where subscription1/subscription2 missing from the document would also apply to the count? In other words if ```subscription1.subscribed = true``` or if ```subscription1``` was missing entirely, both should add to the count? I am trying to figure it out myself, but this level of SQL is a bit foreign to me. Appreciate your answer!

Comment: I tried out the edit and I found two issues: First, while the check for null works when there is one record in the table, if you add a second record (or third, etc) the null count never increases. For example, if you copy the ```values``` with ```id=2``` and run your query, subscription4 will still be 1 (where it should be 2). Second, if the ```subscriptions``` node is missing entirely (so the example value for the jsonb would be simply ```{}```, that is not treated as true/counted. I'm playing around with it to try and fix it myself, but if you want to help I appreciate that as well!

Comment: @Josh  That left-join code was faulty--sorry about that.  I replaced it with a simplified query that can deal with the missing keys conditions.